# Is there a HD version (Higher Quality) .3gp video in youtube for HTML players?

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api, rtsp, 3gp

I was STREAMING  a video to a Chinese Tablet without Flash
from Youtube in HTml5 format and the quality was very poor.

It plays fine without flash, but I would like a higher quality video
in this .3gp format for the tablet.

I think this was meant for a mobile phone that isn't on Wifi, and
only using a network under 3g

rtsp://v6.cache5.c.youtube.com/CjYLENy73wIaLQkNCW3rSEjLahMYDSANFEIJbXYtZ29vZ2xlSARSBXdhdGNoYJqAoPHTrZmFTww=/0/0/0/video.3gp

Is there a way to specify quality of the .3gp file via rtsp
like:

highres, hd1080, hd720, large, medium and small

Or is there any other way to get a high quality video back
to play on android that doesn't require flash installed on the tablet.

ANSWER:

For anyone looking for the answer I found this link:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference#formatsp

Comment: The YouTube Terms of Service expressly forbids to download videos: 5.A. "You shall not download any Content unless you see a 'download' or similar link displayed by YouTube on the Service for that Content."

Comment: I used the word "Downloading" vs. "Streaming".  I am actually streaming the video to a player  ZNEAK

Comment: I am asking a programming question of what parameters I can use in an RTSP request to get a higher quality streaming video: